# java.lang.NullPointerException on Mac, but not on Windows!

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I have searched and searched for a solution to this problem, but it seems no-one else is experiencing it. Here's a description:

I'm creating a tile-based game with some co-programmers. We use a database class to do any and all loading of files and images. Everything works out just wonderfully until my Mac suddenly throws a NullPointerException at my face. The weird thing is it works on another dude's Mac (same model and everything) and it worked just fine on my computer a few minutes before the error. Nothing has been changed in the meantime.

This has happened before, and back then I re-installed the OS which sorted the problem, so it sounds like a tweak in either Eclipse (which I'm using as IDE) or MacOS. Anyone got any ideas?

The project can be found on:
https://github.com/Gadamagaska/Quantum-Man

My stack-trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at entities.Level.getTile(Level.java:24)
    at database.Database.getTile(Database.java:206)
    at core.FoffyMain.drawBottomTiles(FoffyMain.java:82)
    at core.FoffyMain.draw(FoffyMain.java:64)
    at core.Core.gameLoop(Core.java:58)
    at core.Core.run(Core.java:34)
    at core.FoffyMain.main(FoffyMain.java:28)
```

Comment: This means the layers array is still null, meaning that addLayer has never been called. A race condition, perhaps?

Comment: Haakon is right; i suggest you to add bounds checking and some logging to your app also

Comment: I agree, my guess is that under multiple threads the data is seen in a partially initialised state.

Comment: Possibly a threading thing (without looking through the code you got at least the main thread and the AWT EDT). (As a general comment, prefer behaviour-rich objects to primitives, collections to arrays and wherever possible, avoid nulls and make fields final.)

Comment: What you guys are saying seems very logical to me. But how can I make sure the database is created completely before I ask for the tiles? I tried putting a Thread.currentThread.sleep(5000) right after loading the database in FoffyMain, but I still got the same problem. Ouch!

Comment: Have you tried setting an exception breakpoint when NullPointerException is thrown? Set Eclipse to the Debug perspective, then bring up the Breakpoints view and select Add Java Exception Breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but we know at this point where and when the error occurs. The problem right now is to figure out a way to avoid getting the error. This will probably be done by learning more about threads and stuff like that. Oh the agony :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could have checks like this

```
public int getTile(int layer, int x, int y){
    if(layers!=null && layers.length > layer && layers[layer].length > y && layers[layer][y].length > x)
    {
        return layers[layer][y][x];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

or simple handle the null pointer exception

```
public int getTile(int layer, int x, int y) {
    try{

    return layers[layer][y][x];
    }
    catch(NullPointerException npe)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you must remember it's only on my Mac this is a problem. We're tried it on other Mac and Windows systems where it works perfectly fine - but yeah, doing checks is probably something we should add anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this happens only on your Mac ?

Looking at your code, it seems to me that your Level class is trying to access to the layer member before it is initialized.

Try to initialize layer in the constructor of Level instead of the addLayer method, I think it should resolve the problem, or at least a part of it.

Comment: It works just fine on other Macs, but I will definitely try your solution and see if it works. In about 20 minutes, when I'm at my laptop again :)

Comment: I marked this as the answer I accepted, but it seems I'm back at the old problem again. Thanks for the answer, though.